# Open source implementations of BLE stack

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, android-ble

Are there any open source implementations of BLE stack other than BlueZ and Bluedroid?

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of open source BLE stacks:-

- [NimBLE](http://mynewt.apache.org/network/ble/ble_intro/) - Apache mynewt's Bluetooth Low Energy stack.
- [BTstack](http://bluekitchen-gmbh.com/) - BlueKitchen's Bluetooth stack.
- [Zephyr](https://nexus.zephyrproject.org/content/sites/site/org.zephyrproject.zephyr/dev/subsystems/bluetooth/bluetooth.html) - small footprint kernel for resource constrained systems.
- [smallTooth](https://code.google.com/archive/p/smalltooth/source/default/source) - PIC only but may be adaptable to ARM.
- [Blessed](https://github.com/pauloborges/blessed) - BLE stack targeting embedded bare-metal devices (nrf51 only).

I hope this helps.

Comment: NimBLE is here https://github.com/apache/mynewt-nimble

Answer (score 4):

I have used NimBLE, the Apache Mynewt Bluetooth stack in a product.

It works really well on the Nordic NRF51 and NRF52 chips, and is written portably, so it doesn't look like it would be too hard to port it to other platforms.  The code is nice and clean.  Mynewt also comes with secure boot and software upgrade.

Couple of links:

- http://mynewt.apache.org/latest/network/ble/ble_intro/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCmwTWLcVBs

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have for example the Zephyr project: https://nexus.zephyrproject.org/content/sites/site/org.zephyrproject.zephyr/dev/subsystems/bluetooth/bluetooth.html.